# Python Travis-CI: Importing main code in test code

Tags: python, travis-ci, python-unittest

I am writing a simple package in python. In the root directory, my structure currently is,

- my_package

  - **init**.py
  - main_code.py
- tests

  - **init**.py
  - test_main_code.py

I want to import all functions from  main_code.py in test_main_code.py. To achieve this, I did

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\..' + '\my_package')
from main_code import *
```

This runs smoothly on my system. But when I push the code to github and tests are run on travis-ci, all tests fail and return NameError. It says given function name not defined. How do I make sure that tests run on travis-ci as well ?

Comment: See this docs. It has what you needhttps://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths could be different if you run the test somewhere else, so I wouldn't trust any import related to a particular location.
In any case, I always **try to run the tests from the root of the project**.

Then, you can simply try:

`from my_package.main_code import *`